# Keyboard or touchpad shortcut to move windows between screens?

Tags: catalina, shortcut, screen

Anyone knows a way of having a keyboard or touchpad shortcut to move a window from an external screen to the built-in one and vice versa?

Comment: If you hover the mouse pointer over the right most button of the three window controls (minimize, close, maximize), a pop-up will appear that allows you to snap it to a side or move it to another monitor.

Comment: Thanks! That's one good way. Are there any other quicker shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in, but there are third-party programs that provide this functionality. I use the free open source [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com) which provides shortcuts ctrl-opt-cmd-→ to move to the next display to the right and ctrl-opt-cmd-← to move to the next display to the left. It also provides shortcuts for other positioning of windows (e.g., left/right third/half/two-thirds, top, bottom, etc.).